# Как в python выбрать дату из большого числа в каждой строке столбца из excel и записать результат по условию в соседний столбец excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, дата

Есть столбец в excel с номерами ИИН (в Казахстане), где **первые 6 цифр** - это **зашифрованная дата рождения**, а остальные цифры не важны совсем. Например, 760729000345 - это:1976-07-29 (1976 год июль (07) и 29 (дата)) или 961213789432 - это 1996-12-13. Остальные цифры не важны. Нужно из всего **столбца** (там больше 10 тыс записей) в **питоне** **найти дни рождения** и **записать** их в **excel** напротив ИИН в соседний столбец.

Плюс есть часть ИИН, которые юр.лица и там может быть 13 месяц или 65 число. Т.е. в этих строчках нужно поставить "ТОО" и не высчитывать дату.

*Я не понимаю 2 вещи: как к каждой строчке в эксель средствами питона написать дату рождения и как это потом записать в сам эксель.*

У меня получается: либо в эксель только последнее значение записывается, либо сначала одна дата рождения на все ИИН, потом вторая дата на все ИИН итд. Не понимаю, что делаю не так. Уже 3 неделю вожусь. Очень прошу помочь.
Я совсем начинающая в питоне. Прошу сильно не ругать и помочь, пожалуйста, по возможности. Никак не получается.

Вот мой код:

```
import pandas as pd # подгружаем библиотеку, чтобы работать с файлом
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Oct-21\1.xlsx") # загружаем исходный файл
from datetime import date
import time
counter = 0
data_df = df['ИИН'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
for row in data_df:
   year = int(row[0:2])
   if  22 <= year <= 99:
       year += 1900
   else:
       year += 2000
   day = int(row[4:6])
   month = int(row[2:4])
   try:
       data=datetime.date(year,month,day)
       print(data)
   except:
       print("ТОО")
       counter +=1
print(counter)
```

Так код в питоне работает и все считает, но я не понимаю, как его в excel отправить, чтобы он был отдельным столбцом и в каждой строчке свое значение.

Если делаю вот так:

```
from datetime import date
import time
counter = 0
data_df = df['ИИН'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
c = data_df
for row in data_df:
    year = int(row[0:2])
    if  22 <= year <= 99:
        year += 1900
    else:
        year += 2000
    day = int(row[4:6])
    month = int(row[2:4])
    try:
        a = datetime.date(year,month,day)
        b = pd.Series(a)
        df['Дата'] = b
        print(df['Дата'])
    except:   
        print("ТОО")
        counter +=1
```

то каждый раз перезаписывается именно первая строка.

```
Примеры ИИН (столбец из excel из которого берутся данные):

780913204527
```

Спасибо всем за помощь от всей души!
Всем любви и добра!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так.

Создадим функцию

```
def convert_date(x):
    try:
        val = pd.to_datetime(str(x)[:6], yearfirst=True, format='%y%m%d').date()
        if val >= pd.Timestamp.today().date():
            return (val - pd.DateOffset(years=100)).date()
        else:
            return val
    except:
        return 'TOO'

iin = [740603400216,631004302309,760127300474,740418400032,680919301301,730302301686,600727300553,710404301805,661210301930, 691025401917,930513351265,750618300709,731010301512,780315300370,
650704300130, 901006351464........]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_of': iin})
df['new_date'] = df['date_of'].apply(lambda x: convert_date(x))

>>> df

         date_of    new_date
0   740603400216  1974-06-03
1   631004302309  1963-10-04
2   760127300474  1976-01-27
3   740418400032  1974-04-18
4   680919301301  1968-09-19
5   730302301686  1973-03-02
6   600727300553  1960-07-27
7   710404301805  1971-04-04
8   661210301930  1966-12-10
9   691025401917  1969-10-25
10  930513351265  1993-05-13
11  750618300709  1975-06-18
12  731010301512  1973-10-10
13  780315300370  1978-03-15
14  650704300130  1965-07-04
15  901006351464  1990-10-06
16  650611300690  1965-06-11
17  790830401008  1979-08-30
18  880525401338  1988-05-25
19  680101400668  1968-01-01
20  600308400773  1960-03-08
21  860220402979  1986-02-20
22  760916300027  1976-09-16
23  811319300910         TOO
24  620365302226         TOO
```

Что делает функция?

1. Принимает на вход число.
2. Переводит в строку.
3. Берет только первые 6 символов.
4. Переводит в формат *datetime*.
5. От данной даты берем только дату.
6. Если данная дата больше, чем текущая (то есть сегодня), вычитаем 100 лет, приводя ее к нормальному формату (то есть, чтобы не было дат вида 2023 год, 2054 и т.д.)
7. Если данная дата не больше текущей, то оставляем как есть.
8. Пользуясь ***try-except***, если невозможно перевести входное число в дату и выскакивает ошибка - то присваиваем *TOO*

Comment: спасибо большое! Вы - чудо!
Всё заработало идеально. Вылезла проблема только, что 1940 год  - это тоже не люди, а ТОО. ((( Т.е. если дата рождения 1940 год, то нужно ТОО оставить. И можно ТОО заполнить сразу в столбце "new_date" из столбца "клиент" или уже после результата из столбца "клиент" вытащить ТОО. 
Т.е. как-то нужно сделать: если в столбце "клиент" среди прочих слов есть "ТОО", то чтобы в столбец "new_date" тоже ТОО было. Или все с 1940 годом изменить на ТОО. Пока тоже не знаю, как это сделать. Но Ваш код работает просто идеальнейшим образом.Благодарю от всей души!

Comment: по идее такого быть не должно. потому любой формат даты, который поддерживается, он переводит в дату. то есть, если там неправильный день месяца, допустим 32 и выше или неправильный месяц, допустим 13 и выше, то он выдает "ТОО", а так он обрабатывает даже високосные года, то есть 160229 выведет как 2016-02-29

Comment: Ваш код работает идеально! Самым замечательным образом. Это я не правильно изначально оценила данные. ТОО могут иметь ИИН, например, _160740010985_  т.е. день "40" в ТОО не обрабатывает. 160740 - это 1916 -07-40, код выводит 16.07.1940. Причем проблема именно в дате - 40. Остальные - все отлично! Таких не много в таблице моей, и их как-то можно из другого столбца "клиенты" подтянуть, там в названии есть "ТОО" и заменить даты "40" словом ТОО в нужном столбце. Пока не знаю как, но я буду пробовать решить это. 
Отдельное спасибо за разъяснение кода. Очень помогло.

Comment: да, спасибо за пример, понял в чем суть. код обновил, добавил *format* в *pd.to_datetime* , теперь все работает так как надо

Comment: прекрасные новости).  *Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.*